# Unit Test for Delete method does not work properly

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I have a delete method in my service as shown below:

```
public void delete(UUID uuid) {
    final Employee employee = employeeRepository
        .findByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(Constants.ENTITY_NAME));

    final List<EmployeeTranslatable> translatableList = translatableRepository
        .findAllByEntityUuid(uuid);

    employeeRepository.delete(employee);
    translatableRepository.deleteAll(translatableList);
}
```

I created the following unit test.

```
@Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
public void given_Uuid_when_Deleted_then_ThrowEntityNotFoundException() {
    
    // code omitted (employee, translatableList, etc values prepared)

    when(employeeRepository.findByUuid(entityUuid))
        .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(employee));
    when(translatableRepository.findAllByEntityUuid(entityUuid))
        .thenReturn(translatableList);

    employeeService.delete(entityUuid);
    employeeService.findByUuid(entityUuid);
}
```

I expected not find the created entity after calling delete method of service and then throw exception. But it does not work giving an AssertionError. So, is it meningful to test delete methods? If so, how should I test the method above in a unit test?

Comment: you can validate status code returned by delete operation, it could be 200 or 204 based on implementation

Comment: Why should it? You aren't testing anything but a mock not a repository.

Comment: from `.thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(employee))` - `employee` is probably not null.

Comment: @sanjeevRm Thanks a lot, but why do not you post it as answer by using the code in the question?

Comment: @AndrewS Do you meant that my test code is ok? If not, what about posting an example usage to show proper usage? Sorry, but I am really beginner and need your valuable helps.

Comment: Since the test is expecting an exception to be thrown this `when(employeeRepository.findByUuid(entityUuid)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(employee));` should probably be     `when(employeeRepository.findByUuid(entityUuid)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(null));` so that the `.orElseThrow` of the method being tested will be triggered.

Comment: I thought it, but in that case what is the meaning of using `employeeService.delete(entityUuid)` line and then trying to get that record by `employeeService.findByUuid(entityUuid)` ?